# How to do different Animations on the same page but on different screen sizes?

Tags: c#, windows, animation, visual-studio-2015, uwp

I am making a UWP app in which in which I need to different animations for different screen sizes on the same page. I want if screen width is less than 400 this animation should play, If screen with is less than 720 other animation should play. How can I write the code for this in C#.

Answer (score 0):

You can get what you want by using the [`StateTriggers`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-uS/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.visualstate.statetriggers.aspx) property with an [`AdaptiveTrigger`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-uS/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.adaptivetrigger.aspx) to create a declarative rule in XAML markup based on window size. For example:

```
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
        <VisualStateGroup>
            <VisualState>
                <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                    <!--  VisualState to be triggered when window width is <400.  -->
                    <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="0" />
                </VisualState.StateTriggers>
                <VisualState.Storyboard>
                    <Storyboard>
                        <!--  The animation you want to play.  -->   
                    </Storyboard>
                </VisualState.Storyboard>
            </VisualState>
            <VisualState>
                <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                    <!--  VisualState to be triggered when window width is >=400 and <720.  -->
                    <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="400" />
                </VisualState.StateTriggers>
                <VisualState.Storyboard>
                    <Storyboard>
                        <!--  The animation you want to play.  -->
                    </Storyboard>
                </VisualState.Storyboard>
            </VisualState>
            <VisualState>
                <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                    <!--  VisualState to be triggered when window width is >=720.  -->
                    <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="720" />
                </VisualState.StateTriggers>
            </VisualState>
        </VisualStateGroup>
    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
    ...
</Grid>
```

Comment: Thanks for your Ans....I have already done that using these properties and set the animations for different screen sizes..But how to write the play instruction for all the animations on a particular event eg OnClick()...??

Comment: The animation will play automatically when the windows width meets its criteria. For example, when you resize the windows width form 500 to 400, the animation defined in the `VisualState` with `<AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="0" />` will play once. But if you resize the windows width form 500 to 600, there will be no animation.

Answer (score -1):

I think you can use either the SystemParameters.Workarea or the System.Windows.Forms.WorkingArea.  From either you can access the width property.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.systemparameters.workarea.aspx

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.screen.workingarea(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: The question is about UWP.